# Added action button on the toolbar isn't showing up

Tags: java, android

So I recently trying to add another action button beside the overflow icon on the toolbar:

[image]

But by following a tutorial on adding action buttons, I can't get it to show on my toolbar.

Here's my menu/menu_notify.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.jovie.canteen.MenuNotify">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_notify"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24px"
        android:title="@string/action_notify"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

I separated my supposed new action button on a new class which is MenuNotify from my main class, not sure if that's the correct way of adding new action buttons on the toolbar.

MenuNotify.java:

```
package com.example.jovie.canteen;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

/**
 * Created by Jovie on 1/28/2016.
 */
public class MenuNotify extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_notify, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            case R.id.action_notify:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Home.class));
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Btw, my filter icon button is in my main class.

EDIT:
Thanks g2o for the help!

[image]

Comment: Just want to verify the activity class you are using is extending `MenuNotify` correct?

Comment: Yes, the activity class that I'm using for the new action button is MenuNotify.

Comment: If multiple activities are not going to be using the same menu item then the answer from @g2o will make things simpler as you really don't need a base class for the menu items. If you know how to use a debugger put a break point in `onCreateOptionsMenu` to see if it is ever called. Otherwise [Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) something to logcat to see if you are getting there. Based on your previous comment I'm still not sure if you have something like `MainActivity extends MenuNotify` where `MainActivity` is the activity you are starting.

Comment: I tried to write getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_notify, menu); to the onCreateOptionsMenu but since I already have the one for menu (overflow), I decided to create a new class so it will not cause an error  between them which is wrong and yeah g2o's answer is more simple and solved my problem, I'm new to Java btw and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I separated my supposed new action button on a new class which is MenuNotify from my main class, not sure if that's the correct way of adding new action buttons on the toolbar.

There is no need to create new class to add new action button.
Just add

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_notify"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24px"
    android:title="@string/action_notify"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

To your menu/main.xml and add

```
   case R.id.action_notify:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Home.class));
            return true;
```

to the *switch* of your Main class onOptionsItemSelected method.